# How to update ui-resizable-handle while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

My question is a similar one to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726482/jquery-resizable-reposition-handle-after-scroll) with the difference that I need to update all update `ui-resizable-handle`. I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0y1uu1u/) to reproduce the problem.

```
<div id='elementResizable'>
    <h1>Full Nameeeeeeeeeee</h1>
    Title
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="negrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="swgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" id="ngrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" id="sgrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" id="egrip"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" id="wgrip"></div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

A second problem is that the scrollbars always appear even if they do not need to. Probably due to `ui-resizable-handle`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0y1uu1u/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow altogether

```
#elementResizable {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I can't as I need the scrolls if the contents are bigger than width and height.

Comment: use add css attribute when image size increase a specified width and height.

Comment: Actually you should set max min limit to which an item can to resizable,